# Need files to USB boot into my Netbook

Tags: usb, boot, netbook

I have limited use of a computer at the library.  I need to download the files that will allow my USB drive to be bootable to fix my broken Netbook - Aspire One which will not boot.  I know how to set the BIOS to look for it.  With all the restrictions on the library comptuer I can not even upack, unzip or untar, I can only download files directly to my flash drive.  This is probably an nearly impossible question given the circumstances/restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a computer with more access to solve this problem unless you can burn a .ISO to a CD-ROM that you can use for booting.  Of course, if you have the original Windows OS CD-ROM, then you should be able to use that to get into repair mode.

The first thing you should do though is to get a backup image of your laptop's hard drive to maximize your chances of recovering your data, but for this you're going to need another computer.  I like this program a lot as it handles bad sectors really well:

Drive Snapshot Disk Imaging
  http://www.drivesnapshot.de/

If you can burn a CD, this web site will most likely be the most helpful to you:

Bart's Preinstalled Environment (BartPE) bootable live windows CD/DVD
  http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/